# How to remove the space at the end of my output

Tags: python, python-3.x, ord

I am currently trying to figure out a coding issue where I receive a space at the end of my output when I am using ord. If anyone could please help me to fix this error in my code, I will be very grateful.

```
x = input("Dessert idea: ")
for i in x:
  print(ord(i),end=" ")
```

The output always spits out space at the end of the code along with the numbers, 
eg:

```
89 101 101 116 115" "
```

***Space is shown using quotation marks ***

Comment: Why do you use `end=" "` then?

Comment: @L3viathan I needed the output to all be on one line.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code to prevent the last space on the print line;

```
x = input("Dessert idea: ")
for i in x[:-1]:
  print(ord(i),end=" ")
print(ord(x[-1]))
```

This loops through all elements except the last, then adds the last element to the print statement without the space.

Comment: By doing this, the output has no spaces at all. Thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution that makes the code look cleaner IMO:

```
x = input("Dessert idea: ")
print(*(ord(i) for i in x))
```

This unpacks the calls to `ord` into individual arguments, which by default get seperated by spaces, and finishes the line with a newline.

If you're more the functional type, you might prefer `print(*map(ord, x))`

Comment: A much cleaner (pythonic) solution than mine +1.

Comment: Thank you both for helping understand where I went wrong.